# uvm_reg peek function takes long time to return

Tags: system-verilog, uvm, questasim

I thought the `peek` function of `uvm_reg` returned the value in 0 simulation time. Since I needed this functionality, I implemented all my HDL backdoor access paths. This is the code I am using in my scoreboard

```
while (state == DISABLE) begin
  uvm_reg_data_t val = 'hDEADBEEF;
  uvm_status_e status;
  `uvm_info(get_name(), "Start peek", UVM_LOW)

  my_reg_block.my_reg.peek(status, val);

  `uvm_info(get_name(), "End peek", UVM_LOW)

  assert (val == 'h0)

  @posedge(my_vif.clk); //Advance clock

end
```

My intention was: On every clock cycle, in zero simulation time, assert that `my_reg` is 0 when the `state==DISABLE`.

In simulation run, I notice this is fine until around the time that `my_reg` is changing. At the point, Start peek -> End peek takes about 10 clock cycles. In this time, my state is no longer DISABLE and ofcourse val != 'h0. Why does peek take so long to return?

I am using Questasim 10.4a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may take some time, because `peek` is a SystemVerilog task, not a function.

> Function will be executed in 0 Simulation Time, but Tasks can have the
>   timing delays as well.

Here is it's definition.

```
virtual task peek(  output  uvm_status_e    status,     
output  uvm_reg_data_t  value,      
input   string  kind     =  "",
input   uvm_sequence_base   parent   =  null,
input   uvm_object  extension    =  null,
input   string  fname    =  "",
input   int     lineno   =  0   )
```

Comment: you are right, it is a task so possibly could take simulation time. I am not sure where I read that it always takes 0 simulation time. Is this true or am I mistaken?

Comment: Nope. In case of function only you can say that it will be executed in 0 simulation time. In case of task, though 99 out of 100 times, it may get executed in 0 simulation time, but still we can't be sure for tasks. If the post was helpful, then please mark it as answer.